# Sanctions against Russia and Internet subscriptions

Tags: law, russian-federation, sanctions, internet

Sanctions against Russia become heavier by the day, and an answer to that question might not fit the situation in a few weeks. Please consider the situation as of today.

Say a website located in the US works on a subscription-based business model.
The website offers some services, and anyone on the Internet can subscribe to the site and benefit from those services. The subscription being around $1~$5 / monthly.
The services are of an "entertainment" nature (gaming...).

Is it going against the sanctions (from a US PoV) to let a Russian national living in Moscow subscribe to the site, Internet-pay to an US bank, and benefit from the services? Would that collide with the sanctions? (provided that the payment service itself still works from Russia)

Comment: It seems to me it's the kind of question to ask on https://money.stackexchange.com/ The answer would probably depend on what payment method is used. I think most consumer-oriented services like Visa or Paypal have suspended cross-border operations with Russia, but it's a rather vague impression. It's probably best you ask the payment processor you intend to use.

Comment: Not an answer: Could you ask a slightly edited version of this Q to the customer service of the company of interest? I expect that they are aware of the law, regulations, and specific company policy that may vary across companies. For instance, company N (name omitted) does not serve customers from RF and Belarus, and this is per internal company decision, not external law. I know this from personal communication.

Comment: This should probably go to Law.SE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Visa, Mastercard and PayPal no longer work in Russia - it's unlikely now that you can take those payments by accident.
- It would make sense to disable access to payment page by IP geo-block from Russia.
- Some Russian users will use VPN and use other payment options, I don't think you need to, or want to, specifically target these as you have good plausible deniability at this point.